# Ignoring file dates when comparing photos

Tags: winmerge

I want to compare two folders with jpeg files to see which photos are missing from one of the compare folders. Many of the files in each folder have identical contents but WinMerge treats them as different if they show different dates. I have tried the "Ignore Column" plugin without getting any change in the result. There are too many files in the folder to make one-by-one image comparison practical.

Comment: updated tags to better fit your question about winmerge.

Comment: If they show different dates then they're different files for all intended purposes and any software will see them that way.

Comment: I think if might be possible with WinMerge:     https://superuser.com/questions/1709650/is-there-a-way-to-tell-the-winmerge-to-exclude-date-time-comparison

Comment: @John Indeed it should but they say they *have tried the "Ignore Column" plugin without getting any change in the result*. Maybe they did something wrong...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to tell the WinMerge to exclude date/time comparison?](https://superuser.com/questions/1709650/is-there-a-way-to-tell-the-winmerge-to-exclude-date-time-comparison)

Comment: If one ignores date-time, then what are the criteria to determine they're identical? Same filename alone? Same filename and size (size may vary with file system allocation size unit, so that identical files on different drives could show different size)? Byte-by-byte comparison (*slow*)? You might also try other tools: https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/compare-two-directories-files-find-differences/

Comment: Yes, perhaps I did something wrong with the Ignore Column plugin.  However, I will try DrMoishePippik's suggestion and experiment with WinDiff